# how to allow only one checked box per level of a treeview control

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I have searched for last hour looking for vb.net code to ensure only one node per level on a treeview was checked. For example if top level has three nodes and user checks on, the other two should be unchecked. I would like this to work the same for the next two levels of the treeview. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A whole hour? Wow, that's some serious dedication.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

1.- Get the item you just checked and store it in a variable.

2.- Cycle through all the elements at that level (the checked item should tell you who's the parent node and cycle through its children). While you're going through the items, include a condition: if the item at the iteration is the same you just clicked, leave it checked; any other item, uncheck it.

Another approach would be to cycle through every item at the level an uncheck them all, and then check the one you have in the variable.